# Not able to predict with gamma distributed GLM model in H2O

Tags: r, h2o, glm, glmnet

I have just computed a gamma GLM with the h2o package in R.

When I'm trying to predict on the test set I get this error:

> Illegal argument(s) for GLM model: GLM_model_R_1644680218230_95. Details: ERRR on field: _family: Response value for gamma distribution must be greater than 0.

I understand that a gamma model cannot be trained on data with zero response, but one should be able to predict on data with a true value 0 (this is used a a lot in actuaries).

Does any one know a h2o solution? I know I can simply make the model with glm() or something similar, but I'm relying on mean encoded categorical variables (which is really convenient in h2o).

Thanks!

Comment: I might have found a solution. So H2O seems to use the weights (number of claims) into account when predicting. If i set nclaim equal to 1 for all observations on test I was able to predict. This is not the case when I'm using the regular GLM package in R.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in H2O based on your description. We should not fail if you have rows with zero weights. Can you please file an issue in our JIRA? https://h2oai.atlassian.net/jira/dashboards/last-visited

Answer (score 1):

Based on description in comments - this seems like a bug and fix will be needed.